# CSS scale image overlaps

Tags: html, css, scale

I am trying to have scale effect on hover the image. The problem is that the scaled up image overlaps its neighbours, what need to do that the currently hovered image is always on top ?

```css
.col-sm-4 { padding: 0 !important; }

img { max-width: 100%; height: auto; }

.box {
    -webkit-transition:ease 0.7s;
    -moz-transition:ease 0.7s;
    -o-transition:ease 0.7s;
    transition:ease 0.7s;
    display: block;
}

.box:hover {
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <a class="box green">
                <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/525x525/478f00/ffffff">
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <a class="box red">
                <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/525x525/aa001e/ffffff">
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <a class="box blue">
                <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/525x525/00a0b0/ffffff">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Isn't it always on top now?

Comment: it is working as expected ?

Comment: When change the cursor from one box to another it's not ok, after the hover again and It's not working on MS Edge,

Answer (score 0):

You should take margins between every two images. And name the second and third classes different names from the first one.

Then change every class name in the css code and apply for the second and third  what you have done for the first class.